# Correctness Of Minimum Number Of Swaps To Sort An Array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, correctness

The question is from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-swaps-required-sort-array/

I will repeat it below:
Given an array of n distinct elements, find the minimum number of swaps required to sort the array.

Examples:

Input : {4, 3, 2, 1}
Output : 2
Explanation : Swap index 0 with 3 and 1 with 2 to 
              form the sorted array {1, 2, 3, 4}.

Input : {1, 5, 4, 3, 2}
Output : 2

I have solved the problem by doing the following.

1. Sorting the array (n log(n)) time
2. Making a hash to keep track of the swaps required as I compare both the sorted array and the original array. This should be another O(n) time

Total Time Complexity should be: O(n + (n log n)) = O(n log(n))

Below is the code I have written for the same and it works for the test cases provided.

```
def solution(array)

  sorted = array.sort
  puts array.inspect
  puts sorted.inspect

  counter_parts_that_have_been_seen = {}

  number_of_swaps_required = 0

  array.each_with_index do | val, idx |
    if counter_parts_that_have_been_seen[val] == true
      next
    end

    array_val = val
    sorted_val = sorted[idx]

    if array_val != sorted_val
      puts "A swap will be required: array val is #{array_val} and sorted_array_val is #{sorted_val}"
      number_of_swaps_required += 1
      counter_parts_that_have_been_seen[sorted_val] = true
    end
  end

  puts "Number of swaps required are: #{number_of_swaps_required}"

end
```

Now, my question is, how does one verify the CORRECTNESS? I have no sense of weather this approach is correct.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: I haven't really understood your code, but will it work for {3,1,2} ? noting that a position and a value needs to be swapped twice in for that input.

Comment: Well, for that input, it gives 2 swaps. Now, even though technically that is correct. I do not know if my code reached there in the right way. Because, my code assumes that once a swap is made the swapped elements are in their correct position. But that is not the case for {3, 1, 2}. So in other words, let us expand the question: How does one prove that a particular answer is correct?

Comment: Nswaps = Nout_of_place - Ncycles. So the problem can be reduced to finding the out_of_place elements, and the number of cycles.

Comment: Are you ONLY interested to find the minimal number of swaps, or also perform the sort in the most efficient way?

Comment: @FDavidov only the min number of swaps as the problem states. Sort in the most efficient way will be O(n log(n)). It does not quite matter what the array is like.

Comment: @joop Kindly explain in more detail / point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: @KhojBadami, if I understand correctly, the link you provided gets to the result by actually **sorting** the array and counting the swaps. That would not be a **_mathematician way_** to prove something. An yet, since you are not interested in efficiency, I don't quite see a formal way to calculated it except by scanning the array and perform manipulations (like suggested by ROX).

Answer (score 1):

If there is a element that is not in the correct position, then there must also be another element that is also not in it's correct position (the first element need to be placed in some other position that is occupied by another element). If this is represented in the form of a graph, the positions that don't have correct elements will have one edge towards it and on edge from it.  This will end up forming one or more cycles. Now, the positions of the elements in the cycle are all within that cycle. So, we now need to prove that if there are 'n' elements in a cycle, minimum 'n-1' swaps are needed to sort them.
We can prove this be induction.

**Base: n=1** 
Only one element, so already sorted (trivial). This means 0 swaps, ie, n-1 => 1-1 = 0

**Assume if there are k elements in a cycle, it takes min k-1 swaps**

**k+1 elements**
A element in a cycle is has an edge towards the position that it need to be. This position has another edge towards some other position. Now, if we swap the former element, we are removing the former edge and the latter element goes to the swapped position. Now we are left with a cycle of size (k+1)-1 = k. By induction, k cycle requires k-1 swaps. So, k+1 will require (k-1)+1 = k swaps.
[image: Initial cycle(k)]
[image: After one swap (k)]

Comment: This should be the correct proof

Answer (score 0):

Starting at the first element in the unsorted array, check if it is in the correct place, if not swap the correct value into that position. The test can either be done as you did by comparing to a sorted version of the collection, or the selected element can be compared to each element that follows it.

As you go along you may encounter elements that are in the correct position - either because they started in the correct place or they were swapped there when placing an earlier element (the last element must be by the time all other ones have been placed). Just leave those in place and move to the next element.

With this method every swap places at least one element correctly, some swaps will correctly place both.

An element in a correct place can be discounted from the problem - there is never a need to move it from its correct place to sort any other elements.
Also a pair of elements that in each others places (e.g. 3 and 1 in {3,2,1} ) never need to be swapped with any of the other elements. They form their own independent set of elements.

Once you have a method, as above, for obtaining the correct answer, it can obviously be used to evaluate any alternative method.

Comment: But my question is: How does one know that the answer is correct? As in, these are the min number of swaps? For an array of a million numbers, if the answer is 12213, there is no way for me to know if this answer is correct and optimal unless there is a proof of the method. That is what my question is about.

Comment: You can use proof by induction. Discounting any elements at the start that do not require swapping, for n elements, the above method swaps the element that should be first into first place leaving n-1 elements after it. Consider the best way to swap these into order. That number cannot be reduced by the addition of the nth element, nor can the additional swap it requires be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

```
Index :   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
------+-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--
Array :   1  22  32  42  12  83  64  93  73  53
------+-----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--
          A  BBBBBBBBBBBBBB  CC  DD  CCCCCCCCCC
Target:   0   2   3   4   1   8   6   9   7   5
Diffs :   0   1   1   1  -3   3   0   2  -1  -4
Source:   0   4   1   2   3   9   6   8   5   7
```

In this example, the array[] needs to be sorted.

- Target is the index where this position should go after the sort
- source is the position where this index shoul get its value from
- diffs is the relative movement that the item at this index does during the sort

You can see four (cyclic) groups:

- A : 1 member `1`
- B : 4 members `{22,32,42,12}`
- C : 4 members: `{83,93,73,53}`
- D : 1 member: `64`

The groups with 1 member are already sorted: zero swaps needed.
The groups with 4 members can be sorted with 4 swaps each. (the final swap puts *two* elements to their final place)
So the number of swaps needed is **0+3+3+0**

Now you only need to prove that you can sort an N-cycle in N-1 swaps...